# Как в xml найти тег по известному значению и взять значение у определенного аттрибута?

Tags: java, android, xml

Например, нам известно название города Z_city1. Как найти тег, к которому он принадлежит и взять значение аттрибута, допустим, id?

```
<cities>
  <country name="N">
    <city id="37199" region="98765" head="" type="3" country="N" part="" resort="" climate="">N_city1</city>
    <city id="37178" region="48317" head="" type="3" country="N" part="" resort="" climate="">N_city2</city>
  </country>
  <country name="Z">
    <city id="25381" region="12345" head="" type="3" country="Z" part="" resort="" climate="">Z_city1</city>
    <city id="14888" region="34657" head="" type="3" country="Z" part="" resort="" climate="">Z_city2</city>
  </country>
</cities>
```

Answer (score 3):

с помощью xpath-запроса: `//*[text()[contains(.,'Z_city1')]]/@id`